# Error: Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebaseui

I am using Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase Auth and Firebase UI to display data in Recycler View in my application. I am making application in Support Version 28.0.0. Gradle built is successfully synchronized but while running this application an error occurred i.e. "Error: Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2".

Please help me to find compatible versions of Firebase dependencies with given 28.0.0 support version. And also point out what's wrong with this gradle file.

Below is gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.textapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

   //Support Libraries
   //noinspection GradleCompatible
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

   //Firebase Dependencies
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

   //Third Party Libraries
   implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
   implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
   implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
   implementation 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.0'
   implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

   //Facebook Library
   implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

   //Test Libraries
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `firebase-ui-database:3.2.1`instead of the [latest release](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases),  `firebase-ui-database:4.2.1`?

Comment: There is no any reason about that. Do you think using `firebase-ui-database:4.2.1` will solve my problem?

Comment: It might help.  Give it a try.

Comment: Does it work when you are using `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.2.1'`?

Comment: I solved my problem by adding these dependencies in app level gradle file: `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"`
    `annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"`
    `implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'`
    `annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'`